# how to delete card manager applet on the smart card?

Tags: applet, javacard, globalplatform

I have a javacard and when I reset the card, all the applets on the card are cleared except one of them. and it is "Card manager applet" with "A0000000030000" as its AID. I want to know is there any way to delete this applet?! or it is mandatory on the card and there is no way to delete it?
if it is possible to delete it, after deleting it, how we can work with the card? (installing another applet and so on)
thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The card manager is the manager that handles the application management of the card. It also determines the card states. Normally you cannot remove the card manager, especially not through the card manager itself. If you can delete it, it should be through a proprietary API of the card manufacturer.

As a analogy: you are asking Windows or Linux to delete itself.

---

You can however put the card in `TERMINATED` state, after which it is effectively dead. You can even do this from an Applet, if it has the `TERMINATE CARD` privilege, which can be assigned during `INSTALL for INSTALL` when the Applet is instantiated. After this neither the Card Manager not the Applet will work though.

Comment: No, but I know that it keeps files around for processes even if they are replaced (e.g. by an update) so I'm not going to try :) I guess it may keep some files around, but it won't be many, at least not in superuser mode.

Comment: dear @owlstead I am sorry for using this comment to mentioning, but would you please take a look at this quesion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340584/difference-between-verification-and-authentication and this : http://superuser.com/questions/771640/file-structure-inside-a-smartcard  thank you

Comment: @abraham Please don't use comments to point out other questions, thank you.

Comment: @owlstead OK bro.Sorry.