# Difference between verification and authentication?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

As you know, we prove to the card that we are the authentic user, via `INITIAL UPDATE` and `EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATION` commands, as follow :

```
< 80 50 00 00 08 | Host Challenge
> ...
< 84 82 03 00 10 | Host Cryptogram | MAK
> ...
```

I want to know, what is the differece between this authentication process and the `VERIFYING` process with `CLA 20 P1 P2 Lc Data Le` APDU?

All cards support both? or each card use one of this mechanism?

---

**Update:**
As you see, I upload and install my applet on the card successfully , [Without using Verification]!

So why I need verificatin :

```
C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\gpj-20120310>gpj -load e:\helloW.cap -install

C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\gpj-20120310>java -jar gpj.jar -load e:\helloW.cap -ins
tall
Found terminals: [PC/SC terminal ACS CCID USB Reader 0]
Found card in terminal: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 82
Failed to select Security Domain GP211 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 , SW: 6A 82
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 82
Failed to select Security Domain GemaltoXpressPro A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00 , SW:
6A 82
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 0
0
Successfully selected Security Domain OP201a A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 50 00 00 08 A7 C9 58 B7 D1 B6 84 E9
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 00 11 60 01 00 8A 79 0A F9 FF 02 00 31 DF AA 47 16 6E 9
7 B8 02 20 8F 8E A0 1B 88 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 10 0D D7 A4 DF 75 E4 CA 5C 9E EE 25 3F 96 A7 8
A 8B
DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 08 0D D7 A4 DF 75 E4 CA 5C
DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00
DEBUG: packagePath: helloWorldPackage/javacard/
DEBUG: package: helloWorldPackage
DEBUG: package AID: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00
DEBUG: applet AIDs: [01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 ]
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E6 02 00 17 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 08 A0 00 0
0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E6 02 00 17 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 08 A0 00 0
0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E8 00 00 FF C4 82 01 49 01 00 14 DE CA FF ED 01 02 04 0
0 01 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 02 00 1F 00 14 00 1F 00 0F 00 0B 00 2E 00
0C 00 7D 00 18 00 12 00 00 00 6F 00 02 00 01 00 0B 01 01 00 04 00 0B 01 02 01 07
 A0 00 00 00 62 01 01 03 00 0F 01 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 00 08 06 0
0 0C 00 80 03 00 FF 00 07 01 00 00 00 1C 07 00 7D 00 01 10 18 8C 00 00 7A 05 30
8F 00 01 3D 8C 00 02 18 1D 04 41 18 1D 25 8B 00 03 7A 02 23 18 8B 00 04 60 03 7A
 19 8B 00 05 2D 1A 03 25 11 00 FF 53 5B 32 1A 04 25 11 00 FF 53 5B 29 04 1F 60 0
8 11 6E 00 8D 00 06 16 04 73 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 09 18 19 8C 00 07 70 08 11 6D
00 8D 00 06 7A 05 22 19 8B 00 05 2D 7B 00 08 92 32 7B 00 08 03 1A 03 1F 8D 00 09
 3B 19 03 1F 8B 00 0A 7A 08 00 18 00 02 00 01 00 01 03 00 0B 48 65 64 61 79 74 2
0
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E8 00 00 FF C4 82 01 49 01 00 14 DE CA FF ED 01 02 04 0
0 01 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 02 00 1F 00 14 00 1F 00 0F 00 0B 00 2E 00
0C 00 7D 00 18 00 12 00 00 00 6F 00 02 00 01 00 0B 01 01 00 04 00 0B 01 02 01 07
 A0 00 00 00 62 01 01 03 00 0F 01 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 00 08 06 0
0 0C 00 80 03 00 FF 00 07 01 00 00 00 1C 07 00 7D 00 01 10 18 8C 00 00 7A 05 30
8F 00 01 3D 8C 00 02 18 1D 04 41 18 1D 25 8B 00 03 7A 02 23 18 8B 00 04 60 03 7A
 19 8B 00 05 2D 1A 03 25 11 00 FF 53 5B 32 1A 04 25 11 00 FF 53 5B 29 04 1F 60 0
8 11 6E 00 8D 00 06 16 04 73 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 09 18 19 8C 00 07 70 08 11 6D
00 8D 00 06 7A 05 22 19 8B 00 05 2D 7B 00 08 92 32 7B 00 08 03 1A 03 1F 8D 00 09
 3B 19 03 1F 8B 00 0A 7A 08 00 18 00 02 00 01 00 01 03 00 0B 48 65 64 61 79 74 2
0
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E8 80 01 4E 3A 29 20 20 00 00 00 00 05 00 2E 00 0B 06 8
0 03 00 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 03 80 03 02 03 80 03 03 03 80 0A 01 06 80 07 01
06 00 00 5F 05 00 00 00 06 80 10 02 03 80 0A 08 09 00 12 00 00 00 0E 05 06 04 0A
 07 07 1D 10 08 07 04 05 07 07
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E8 80 01 4E 3A 29 20 20 00 00 00 00 05 00 2E 00 0B 06 8
0 03 00 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 03 80 03 02 03 80 03 03 03 80 0A 01 06 80 07 01
06 00 00 5F 05 00 00 00 06 80 10 02 03 80 0A 08 09 00 12 00 00 00 0E 05 06 04 0A
 07 07 1D 10 08 07 04 05 07 07
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E6 0C 00 29 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 0B 01 02 0
3 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 01 00 02 C9 00 00

DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 E6 0C 00 29 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 0B 01 02 0
3 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 01 00 02 C9 00 00

DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 90 00
```

Comment: It's MAC (Message Authentication Code), not MAK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize update and ext auth commands are to establish secure channel between off card and on card entity.
While 00 20 .... apdu is for verify card manager pin.
So all cards which are GP compliance will support both.
There is card manager which is the owner of card so to authenticate urself or say to reach card manager u can use initialize update and ext auth.
OR u can select card manager and use 00 20... command to verify urself to card manager.

Comment: Thank you, I have a GemPlus javacard. do you know what is it's default PIN for verifying?

Comment: Sorry no idea abt Gemplus cards :-(

Comment: U can try 010203040506708 this is just a guess ;-)

Comment: OK, Thanks :) . Do you know what capabilities of card activate(enable to use) after verifying?

Comment: After select card manager and verify card manager pin u will be able to send GP compliance commands to card for ex get status ,putkey,install....etc

Comment: Did u got ur answer? If yes then accept or let me know if u want know something else.

Comment: No! I have a card, and I can sent Install, Delete and other GP compliant commands without verification! why?!

Comment: As you can see in ur logs EBUG: Command APDU: 80 50 00 00 08 A7 C9 58 B7 D1 B6 84 E9 DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 00 11 60 01 00 8A 79 0A F9 FF 02 00 31 DF AA 47 16 6E 9 7 B8 02 20 8F 8E A0 1B 88 90 00 DEBUG: Command APDU: 84 82 00 00 10 0D D7 A4 DF 75 E4 CA 5C 9E EE 25 3F 96 A7 8 A 8B DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00 DEBUG: Command APDU: 84 82 00 00 08 0D D7 A4 DF 75 E4 CA 5C DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00

Comment: Here is init update and ext auth after that u r installing cap or say running GP command.

Comment: Yes I know. but when I need verification? as you see I can do anything after authentication!

Comment: There is no need of verification since u r using init update and ext auth.

Comment: And is there any way to use verifying instead of initial update and external auth? or my card just support this method?

Comment: Your card supports both method but the point is u dont know the card manager pin.

Comment: Please refrain from using UTub (YouTube) style language on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

According to : ISO 7816-4: Interindustry Commands for Interchange for smart card.

The VERIFY command initiates the **comparison** in the card of the verification data sent from the interface device with the reference data stored in the card (e.g. password).

The AUTHENTICATE command initiates the **computation** of the authentication data by the card using the challenge data sent from the interface device and a relevant secret (e.g. a key) stored in the card.

Comment: Thank you, I have a GemPlus javacard. do you know what is it's default PIN for verifying?

Comment: Hmm..it 0000 or 1234 ,also If above is answer to your question then please mark/up vote. Thanks

Comment: I'll upvote soon! I can't upvote now! (it's need at least 15 rep).
using DEK_KEY, S_ENC and S_MAK Keys for external authenticate doesn't prove that I am authentic user to card manager? if yes, why I must verify? what capabilities of card activate(enable to use) after verifying?

Comment: It's nice to quote standards, but for the `INITIALIZE UPDATE` and `AUTHENTICATE` commands defined by GP: they are defined with a class byte with the highest order set to 1 (`80` or `84`). This means that these are *proprietary* commands not described in ISO 7816-4. Of course, that does not mean that the gist of your answer is not correct, these commands certainly use a symmetric challenge-response protocol.